# Div wont extend to bottom of its contents when divs inside it are floated

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs as columns, both are floated left and set to clear none. Their container div has a background image at the top, so the background is at the top of both columns.

I want to be able to also have a background image at the bottom of the columns. I've created another div which sits inside the container div (but outside the columns) and set a background image to its bottom.

The problem is that this div doesn't extend to the bottom of the columns it contains. How can I make it do this? I've tried playing around with floats and clearing but without any luck.

Comment: can you provide some code or better a jsfiddle live example ?

Comment: Problems with floated objects are often that you need to change the `div` they are in with a simple `overflow:auto`. I don't know if this also accounts for your problem, because you haven't provided code yet.

Comment: you should accept an answer or say which ones worked and which didnt, not ask a question then presumably get your answer and forget about the site

Answer (score 1):

Give the outer `<div>` "overflow: hidden;".

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/eNEwk/)

Answer (score 0):

try setting the outer div to float:left as well

Answer (score 0):

You can set in the last element inside the main container the following:

```css
#lastElement:after {
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
}
```

This will create a new block element with clear and will fix your issue. The answer given by Pointy works too but fails if the width/height of the container is fixed and the inside content can be changed (more text, or add another image) and then, the inner content of the container will get itself hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a div at the bottom of your column container div like this:

```
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
```

It's a bit of a stab in the dark but the best I can think of without seeing the code myself, hope it helps.